# Where do I change the routing for the login page in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5.3

When a logged in user visits the page www.testdomain.com/login, they are redirected to www.testdomain.com/home. I want to change it to redirect to www.testdomain.com/tasks, where do I go to change this route?

I am using Laravel's built in authentication system. And I already changed app\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php to have the line

```
protected $redirectTo = '/tasks';
```

And php artisan route:list is as follows

```
|        | POST     | login                  |        | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                        | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD | login                  | login  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                | web,guest
```

When I open app\http\controllers\auth\LoginController.php file, I cannot find any line of code relating to the 'LoginController@login' or 'LoginController@showLoginForm' route controllers.

This is my app\http\controllers\auth\LoginController.php file

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/tasks';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add The following code in AuthController.

```
protected $redirectTo = '/tasks';
```

If you have created your own Controller, then add following traits in your LoginController,

```
use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to edit the `app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php` file.

from

`return redirect('/home');`

to

`return redirect('/tasks');`